# Mirror UIImagePicker result preview image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

How do I mirror the result preview image made by the selfie camera in `UIImagePickerController`?
I've tried multiple approaches, `cameraViewTransform` doesn't work for me, cause it mirrors the live preview as well.
Can I in any way account for selfie camera mirrored setting in iOS?

Comment: see this for help : [How do I mirror a UIImage picture from UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129282/how-do-i-mirror-a-uiimage-picture-from-uiimagepickercontroller/3130227)

Comment: I have seen this post, most of it is focused on mirroring the actual image, with my problem being displaying the mirrored image to the user in a preview after capturing an image in the standard `UIImagePickerController` interface

Answer (score 0):

So I've found this interesting solution

```
- (void) imageTaken {
if (_picker.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront) {
    NSMutableArray *subviews = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:_picker.view];
    while ([subviews count] != 0) {
        UIView *subview = [subviews firstObject];
        [subviews removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [subviews addObjectsFromArray:subview.subviews];
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            subview.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_picker.cameraViewTransform, -1, 1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

and

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(imageTaken) name:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" object:nil];
```